# Find $\lim_{(x,y)\to (3,1)\\(x≠3y)} \frac{3x^2-5xy-5y^2+2x-4y}{x-3y}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (3,1)\\(x≠3y)} \frac{3x^2-5xy-5y^2+2x-4y}{x-3y}$$

**My work so far**

$$\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{3x^2-5xy-5y^2+2x-4y}{x-3y}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{3(3)^2-5(3)y-5y^2+2(3)-4y}{3-3y}$$

$$=\frac{-5y^2-19y+33}{3-3y}$$

and

$$\lim_{y\to 1} \frac{3x^2-5xy-5y^2+2x-4y}{x-3y}$$

$$\lim_{y\to 1} \frac{3x^2-5x(1)-5(1)^2+2x-4(1)}{x-3(1)}$$

$$=\frac{3x^2-3x-9}{x-3}$$

Would anything else need to be done? Also, if my process correct?

Comment: You need to calculate the limit when both $x$ and $y$ tends to their values simultaneously.

Comment: The numerator isn't even going to $0$.

Comment: divide the numerator by denominator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the iterated limits do not exist, as it tends to infinity. so the limit does not exist, otherwise it would not matter how you approach the point it would tend to some point $(x_{0},y_{0})$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thanks for that! Superb explanation and it makes sense now.

Comment: I worked this out and wanted to see if I'm on the right track: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (3,1)\\(x≠3y)} \frac{3(3)^2-5(3)(1)-5(1)^2+2(3)-4(1)}{3-3(1)}=\frac{9}{0}$$

Comment: Yes, you are. You can do it as the result is not a indeterminate form.

Comment: Thanks gxep for the confirmation. It makes sense now.